# Bash ranges of non digit or letters

Tags: bash

I played around with bash `{..}` constructs today. I knew

```
{a..z}
```

would generate all letters,

```
{0..9}
```

digits etc. (numbers in general obviously), but By mistake I got

```
{Z..a}
```

yielding:

```
Z [  ] ^ _ ` a
```

The characters in between "Z" (90) and "a" (97) are the ASCII 91-96. The astute reader will notice there is a character missing - "\", 92. I'm guessing because of it's special nature. Is this **expected behavior** as output? Specifically, I'm guessing the `\` is being used to escape the space in front of it after substitution, but @John1024 notes that:

```
echo {Z..a}a
```

will complain on missing backticks, while the previous version (no `a`) does not. **How exactly is substitution working? Is there a bug?**

Second, I guessed the range operator is cooler than I thought and can do any range of ASCII characters I choose, but `{[.._}` for example fails. Am I missing something to make this work or is this just a curiosity? **Are there any more ranges besides letters/digits I can use? and if not, why not do nothing (fail, echo as is) for 'jumping' from caps to lower?**

Answer (score 4):

The `\` *is* being generated; however, it subsequently appears to be treated as escaping the following space. Compare:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'Z' '[' ']' '^' '_' '`' 'a'
Z
[
]
^
_
`
a
$ printf '%s\n' {Z..a}
Z
[

]
^
_
`
a
```

The extra blank line following the `[` is the space escaped by the backslash generated by `{Z..a}`.

Comment: Very good.  Also, note that  `echo {Z..a}a` generates the error `bash: bad substitution: no closing "\`" in a` indicating that the backquote is an active character in this form even though it is  __not__ active in the form `echo {Z..a}`.

Comment: And what is the reason `{[.._}` does not work? Can the characters used in brace expansion be only letters and numbers?

Comment: @PesaThe `man bash` says the characters "must be of the same type."  AFAICT, though, the word `type` is not clearly defined but it might mean that bash wants either numbers or letters.

Comment: I gathered as much, but I was wondering as to the order of things. @John1024 clinched it for me - the range is substituted then the result is used as is (I typed it manually) which I guess is expected behavior. Does anyone have a source saying why only letters/numbers work then? I'm wondering if there is a letter digit check, but the output is then just ASCII based.

Comment: @John1024 I read your first comment again, and see now I misunderstood. Seems like one of the behaviors is unexpected (without 'a' should complain?), so is this is a bug?

Comment: @kabanus Yes, the behavior seems completely inconsistent.  For consistency, if backslash is always active, then backquote should always be active but it isn't.  For consistency, if backquote is active/inactive in one case, it seems it should be the same in the other but it isn't.  Lacking a better explanation, I agree: this seems to be a bug.

Comment: One thing I meant to do, but didn't until just now: run the output of the `{Z..a}` example through `hexdump`. Although the backslash appears to be escaping a space (and so removed during quote removal), that space doesn't actually appear in the output. There are two consecutive newlines, so the backslash/space combo appears to turn into a null character some how. I agree with there being a bug in `bash`'s handling here.

Comment: (`zsh`, by the way, simply outputs a backslash as one might expect.)

Answer (score 1):

A special variable [`obase`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html#SEC6) can be used with [`bc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html) to print almost any character range(s):

```
for n in {91..95}; do printf "\x$(echo "obase=16; $n" | bc)"; done
```

Result:

```
[\]^_
```

↳ https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html#TOC6